# Ideas for web content testing using protractor?

Tags: html, css, testing, protractor, end-to-end

Has anyone got any ideas on what else is good to test regarding web content and stuff that protractor is capable of testing?

Currently I have tested links to see if they go to the correct page? also I have tested text colour and decoration when hovering over text and expected it to change colour?

testing to see if text appears where it should be seems a waste.
Just wondering if anyone on here had any good ideas on something worth testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Protractor is a very powerful tool to test your application, validation, navigation or even CRUD-operations (Create, Read, Update and Delete).

For example I'm currently developing end-to-end tests for an angular app, I go through every step the user should go through and check where it could go wrong.
If the user enters a wrong e-mail, does the validation appear?

You can generate a list of tests that you run every time you launch a new build of your website.

Comment: ah yes that makes sense I guess. any ideas on how to get protractor to click inside a search box and then commit the search?

Comment: You would want to make protractor LOCATE your search box, which is done with javascript locators: 
    element(by.id('searchBox')).sendKeys('yourQuery');
And then make it click the search button:
    element(by.id('searchButton')).click();

In case you're not yet familiar with this: http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/tutorial

Comment: it's close but it is saying `unknown error: cannot focus element`

Comment: That sounds like a different question, could you indicate wether this answered your question and you can create a new question where you include your HTML-code etc.